# Introducir condicional ternario en PHP

Tags: php

No sé cómo incluir un condicional en un `input` que se muestra a través de PHP.

He intentado con:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='status' placeholder='Introduce un estatus' value='"
. if(isset($_POST['guardar'])) { 
     $ubicacion;
} else {  
     $informacion_perfil['ubicacion'];
} . "'>";
```

Me da un error: `syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)`, pero no sé cómo solventarlo, y evidentemente así estaría mostrando todo el condicional, cuando sólo quiero mostrar `$ubicacion` o `$informacion_perfil['ubicacion']` en función de si se cumple una condición u otra.

La única solución que he encontrado es esta:

```
if(isset($_POST['guardar'])) {
   echo "<input type='text' name='status' placeholder='Introduce un estatus' value='" .  $status . "'>";
} else {
   echo "<input type='text' name='status' placeholder='Introduce un estatus' value='" . $informacion_perfil['estado'] . "'>";
}
```

Me gustaría saber si se puede hacer el mismo código en tan sólo una línea.

Comment: Hola @JetLagFox. Más allá de la respuesta que está en la pregunta duplicada, ¿qué tiene de malo usar un `if` común y corriente? Por otro lado, deberías sanitizar el valor recibido en un POST, de lo contrario podrías estar inyectando código en la página

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es fácil con el comparador ternario de PHP

```
echo "<input type='text' name='status' placeholder='Introduce un estatus' value='" . (isset($_POST['guardar']) ? $ubicacion : $informacion_perfil['ubicacion']) . "'>";
```

Su uso es `condición` ? `sentencia TRUE` : `sentencia FALSE`;

Comment: ¿A ustedes les carga el input de tipo text?
Yo veo el valor pero no me carga el input text.

Comment: Tienes razón, lo he hecho de cabeza y no estaba bien cerrado. Corregido.

Comment: Ese era el problema... ahora si.!

Answer (score 1):

En una sola línea no me sale pero de esta forma también queda más reducido que tu segunda propuesta, por si te puede servir.

```
if(isset($_POST['guardar'])) { $aux=$ubicacion;} else {  $aux=$informacion_perfil['ubicacion'];}

$salida = "<input type='text' name='status' placeholder='Introduce un estatus' value='".$aux."'>";

echo $salida;
```

También he visto que hay en la documentación de php oficial unas [estructuras alternativas](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) por si te pueden servir de ayuda.

Comment: Según las [PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#if-elseif-else), que pretende ser un estándar _de facto_ para la codificación en PHP, cada sentencia del IF debe estar en una línea, sin perjuicio de la debida indentación y colocación de las llaves.

Comment: Lo sé y así lo hago, si lo dejé todo el `if`en una línea fue por requisito de @JetLagFox en su mensaje :)

Comment: En ese caso, el [operador ternario](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) es una solución más limpia y adaptada a este tipo de estándares. Ten en cuenta que toda una aplicación puede desarrollarse en una sola línea, pero pobre de aquel que venga detrás.

Comment: Por supuesto... en eso estoy de acuerdo y también pobre de aquel que venga detrás jajajaja Aunque he probado y no me carga el input en el html, ¿A tí también te pasa @Muriano? ¿O si se te ve el input cargado?

Comment: Tienes razón, ya está corregido.

Answer (score 1):

Como propuesta de solución yo guardaría en una variable ambas posibilidades, en vez de incluir un if en el value de un input.

Por ejemplo...

```
if(isset($_POST['guardar'])) { 
     $value = $ubicacion;
} else {  
     $value = $informacion_perfil['ubicacion'];
}
```

Y luego simplemente llamo a la variable en el `input`, tal que así.

```
echo "<input type='text' name='status' placeholder='Introduce un estatus' value='" .$value. "'>";
```